# Using Filter expression in C#

Tags: c#, filtering

From the below code I would like to filter and wish to get only `MasterproductID = 1` and its childs under it. By filtering `MasterproductID = 2` and `MasterproductID = 3`.
May I know how to do that? Thanks for your help.

```
class TreeNode
{
    public int MasterProductId;
    public int? ParentId;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var list = new List<TreeNode>{

        new TreeNode{ MasterProductId = 1 },
        new TreeNode{ MasterProductId = 4, ParentId = 1 },
        new TreeNode{ MasterProductId = 7, ParentId= 4 },
        new TreeNode{ MasterProductId = 5, ParentId = 1 },
        new TreeNode{ MasterProductId = 6, ParentId = 1 },

        new TreeNode{ MasterProductId = 2 },
        new TreeNode{ MasterProductId = 7, ParentId = 2 },
        new TreeNode{ MasterProductId = 8, ParentId= 7 },

        new TreeNode{ MasterProductId = 3 },

    };

    foreach (var item in Level(list, null, 0))
    {
        if (item.Value == 0)
        {
            Response.Write(String.Format("<b>MasterProductId={0}, Level={1}", item.Key, item.Value) + "</b><br />");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write(String.Format("MasterProductId={0}, Level={1}", item.Key, item.Value) + "<br />");
        }
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, int>> Level(List<TreeNode> list, int? parentId, int lvl)
{
    return list
        .Where(x => x.ParentId == parentId)
        .SelectMany(x =>
            new[] { new KeyValuePair<int, int>(x.MasterProductId, lvl) }.Concat(Level(list, x.MasterProductId, lvl + 1))
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Level` method already does almost exactly what you want. If the `foreach` was modified to specify the `ParentId` of 1:

```
foreach (var item in Level(list, 1, 0))
```

Then it will produce output for nodes 4, 7, 8, 5 and 6. That is, it returns the *descendants* of a node.

If you also want to include the specified parent node, you only need to concat it to the resulting list. For example:

```
private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, int>> LevelIncl(
                 List<TreeNode> list, int parentId)
{
    return new[] {new KeyValuePair<int, int>(parentId, 0)}
              .Concat(Level(list, parentId, 1));
}
```

And then:

```
foreach (var item in LevelIncl(list, 1))
```

That will produce output for nodes 1, 4, 7, 8, 5 and 6.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason, not obvious from your example code or your explanation, that you cannot simply use this?

```
.Where(x => x.MasterProductId == 1 || (x.ParentId.HasValue && x.ParentId.Value == 1))
```

---

If, as suggested, you are looking for a recursive ancestor relationship, not just a parent relationship, some updates to your data structure would very much facilitate the goal.

```
class TreeNode
{
    public int MasterProductId;
    public int? ParentId;

    private TreeNode parent; 
        // How this gets set requires other data structures, and some knowledge of
        // how you are loading the data--but this should give you the outline of an idea

    public bool HasAncestor(int referenceId, int ancestor) {

        if (!parentId.HasValue) 
        { 
            return false 
        };

        if (parentId.Value == ancestor) 
        {
            return true;
        }

        return parent.HasAncestor(ancestor);                
    }
}
```

You would then be able to do:

```
 .Where(x => x.MasterProductId == 1 || x.HasAncestor(1))
```

The best way to implement the parent `attribute` in `TreeNode` depends the rest of your implementation details--I would encapsulate it in a container class that has a `Map<int, TreeNode>` to track all of the known nodes.   That map would be used on construction of a `TreeNode` to set the parent reference.

Comment: Perhaps the query needs to be recursive?

Comment: If that is the case, the current data model is very poorly designed to permit it, and really requires some restructuring to make it reasonably efficient and elegant to do.   Adding a true reference to parent, in the in-memory representation (even if this stuff comes, for example, from a SQL table) would be the best approach in my opinion.